# How to implement a DataGrid when a list of objects of the same class and a list of string of properties are given?

Tags: wpf

I would like to implement a DataGrid that displays data of objects with the same class. A list, which accepts generic type of class, of objects called `objectsList` and a list of string of properties called `propertiesToDisplay` are provided so that the DataGrid can choose which properties of the objects to be shown, according to `propertiesToDisplay`. How can I implement it?

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="SomeProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="700">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsList}">
        <!-- Anything Else? -->
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         // How is the binding?
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class ViewModel<T>
{
     private IList<T> _objectsList;
     public IList<T> ObjectsList
     {
         get
         {
             return _objectsList;
         }
         set
         {
             _objectsList = value;
         }
     }
     private IList<string> _propertiesToDisplay;
     public IList<string> PropertiesToDisplay
     {
         get
         {
            return _propertiesToDisplay;
         }
         set
         {
            _propertiesToDisplay= value;
         }
     }

    // Constructor
    public ViewModel(IList<T> objectsList, IList<string> propertiesToDisplay)
    {
         // Please help me to correct the following code
         PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = null;
         foreach (var propertyName in propertiesToDisplay)
         {
             propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
             var names = propertyInfos.Select(x => x.Name);
             if (!names.Contains(propertyName))
             {
                 throw new ArgumentException("");
             }
         }
         try
         {
             ObjectsList = objectsList; 
             foreach (var obj in objectsList)
             {
                  foreach (var propertyName in propertiesToDisplay)
                  {
                      PropertiesToDisplay.Add(propertyInfos.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(propertyName)).FirstOrDefault().GetValue(obj, null).ToString());    
                  }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The nested foreach loops over all properties of all items makes no sense. You don't need the PropertiesToDisplay list at all. What you actually want is to create the appropriate DataGrid Columns dynamically from the list of property names. Also don't forget to assign an instance of your view model to the DataContext property of the MainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the columns dynamically in the view based on the `PropertiesToDisplay` source property. Something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel<YourClass> viewModel = new ViewModel<YourClass>(..., ...);
        foreach (string column in viewModel.PropertiesToDisplay)
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = column, Binding = new Binding(column) });
        dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsList}" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this violate MVVM?

Comment: @TomFong: No, creating columns isn't the responsibility of any other component than the view or the control. You are creating them in the exact same view as you would if you had defined them directly in the XAML markup. The only difference is that you write code to make it dynamic. Creating columns in a view model would break the pattern.